# Why it is recommended to use only Heap Buffers with [byte] operations in ChannelOutboundHandler.?

Tags: java, memory, netty, heap-memory, directmemory

We are working on open-sourcing an api gateway and using **Netty** as underlying framework.

I came across Norman Maurer slides. In one of the slides, he mentioned

> Only use heap buffers if need to operate on byte[] in
>   ChannelOutboundHandler! By default direct ByteBuf will be returned by
>   ByteBufAllocator.buffer(...).
>
> Take this as rule of thumb

What is the reason behind this thumb of rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part is "if need to operate on byte[]". As only when using heap `ByteBuf`s it's possible to use `byteBuf.array()` to access the underlying `byte[]` without doing and extra memory copy.